# R: using Solve in matlib to solve system of equations where # unknowns > # eqns

Tags: r, linear-algebra

```
library(matlib)
A <- matrix(c(1, 1/7, 1, 2/7, 1, 3/7, 1, 4/7, 1, 5/7, 1, 6/7), 2, 6)
b <- c(1,0.4)
showEqn(A, b)
```

[image]

I am trying to use the `matlib` function to help me find values of $x_1, ..., x_6$ such that they satisfy the above equations. I know there are many different combinations of $x_1, ..., x_6$ such that the above 2 equations can be satisfied. How can I find those values of $x_1, ...., x_6$? I tried using `Solve(A, b, fractions = TRUE)` but that does not give me a set of possible solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the number of unknown is greater thab the number of equations you have, there is an infinite number of solutions. Indeed, if the difference is 1 the solution is a line, if the difference is 2 the solution is a plane, and so on.

In general, if the number of variables is N and the number of equations is M (and we can assume the equations to be linearly independent), the solution will be a shape of dimension N-M embedded in  a space of dimension N.

So what you obtain by solving systems where N is greater than M will be an equation describing the relation between some x_i, e.g. the equation of a line. R being mainly designed to work on numbers and perform arithmetic rather than working with symbolic math, it is probably not the best suited software for this purpose. However, if you want to stay with R there are some libraries that offer this possibility, see this [post](https://www.r-bloggers.com/using-r-as-a-computer-algebra-system-with-ryacas/) for example.